# What is the lookahead symbol?

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar

In the grammars (for example **LL(1)**), **1** denotes the lookahed symbol. In practice i don't understand what is this symbol. To understand, i need a simple and practical example.

Comment: Such a lookahead is a symbol that is interpreted "command like" by some processors. It allows to peek ahead, so to read and evaluate a portion of the input stream _without actually forwarding the location of the stream_. As an effect the next read operation will read the same sequence. The benefit: you can see in advance what you have to expect from the input to come. Sorry, no example at hand currently...

Comment: Seems like a question for [Programmer's StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**LL(1)** grammars help you decide immediately which **grammar rule** you will use. This one lookahead token means that you only have to read the next one character from the current character you are reading.

**LL(1)** grammars help you to decrease complexity to `O(n)` and have no backtracking on parsing the input.

*[Wikipedia Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser#Concrete_example)*

Let `%` to be the character you are reading and the input string to be `( a + a )`

A LL(1) grammar :

```
S -> F (Rule1)

S -> ( S + F ) (Rule2)

F -> a (Rule3)
```

Parsing Table is :

```
    (   )   a   +   $
S   2   -   1   -   -
F   -   -   3   -   -
```

Then you have:

`%( a + a )` ( read the start of the string and lookahead is (, so decide to apply Rule2 according to the parsing table)

The abstract syntax tree is now :

```
            S
        / / | \ \
       (  S + F  )
```

Then you consume `(`. And you continue the same way.

Step 2:

```
            S
        / / | \ \
       (  S + F  )
          |
          F
          |
          a
```

Step 3:

```
            S
        / / | \ \
       (  S + F  )
          |   |
          F   a
          |
          a
```

You can see Wikipedia example that uses a stack, instead of an abstract syntax tree in the exactly same way.

Comment: Nitpick: the unit of lookahead is tokens, not characters. A token may be comprised of more than one character.